# @valid not working as expected. Error message displaying on console not on postman

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, validation

@valid not working as expected. Error message displaying on console not on Postman.

I am using 2.4 SpringbootStarter and have added the new dependency manually.

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Error message on Postman:

```
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.
```

Error message on Console:

```
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage=' First Name is blank. Please provide First Name.', propertyPath=firstName, rootBeanClass=class banking_atm.Model.Customer, messageTemplate=' First Name is blank. Please provide First Name.'}
]
```

Entity Class:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2,message =" First Name is blank. Please provide First Name.")
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private List<SavingAccount> savingAccount;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
    private List<CheckingAccount>checkingAccount;

    public Customer() {
    }

getters and setter...
```

Controller class: FYI I have added @Validated on top on controller class.

```
import banking_atm.Service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
@Validated
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping(value ="/all")
    public List<Customer> getAll() {
        return customerService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value ="/id/{id}")
    public Customer getId(@PathVariable("id")Integer findById) {
        return customerService.getId(findById);
    }

    @PostMapping(value ="/newsavingaccount")
    public String newSavingAccount(@RequestParam("firstName")String firstName,@RequestParam("lastName")String lastname,@RequestParam("addBalance")Integer addingBalance){

        return customerService.newSavingAccount(firstName, lastname, addingBalance);
    }

    @PostMapping(value ="/newcheckingaccount")
    public String newCheckingAccount(@Valid @RequestParam("firstname")  String firstName, @RequestParam("lastname")String lastname, @RequestParam("addbalance")Integer addingBalance){

        return customerService.newCheckingAccount(firstName, lastname, addingBalance);
    }
```

ExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {MethodArgumentNotValidException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<?> customValidationErrorHandling(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception){

        ApiException apiException = new ApiException(
                "Validation Error",
                exception.getBindingResult().getFieldError().getDefaultMessage(),
                ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z")));



        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank You.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look into server logfiles for more information.

Comment: We need some more information here in order to recreate the issue locally. Please add complete code for controller and the class you refer to as "Entity Class". BR

Comment: I have updated my question per your request .

Answer (score 1):

The validation is not happening in your Controller, it is happening in your Customer @Entity annotated class - that is the cause of your issue. Instead of expected `MethodArgumentNotValidException` the `TransactionSystemException` is thrown, which produces http code 500 in Postman.

`CustomerController` class is annotated with @Validated, but you did not define any validation rules in your Controller methods. Instead of @Valid you need a validating annotation (e.g. @NotNull, @NotBlank, etc.). So change your method (applies also for all other methods) like this:

```
@PostMapping(value ="/newcheckingaccount")
public String newCheckingAccount(@NotBlank @RequestParam("firstname") String firstName, ...
```

In my German blog I have written an article about validation with Spring and Hibernate-Validator - there you will see a full example:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/11/validation-with-spring.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have tried what you suggested but I am still getting the same error. Any other suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: To debug your issue, I would change the ExceptionHandler so that it uses Exception instead MethodArgumentNotValidException. Then you will get more details about the source of your unexpected TransactionSystemException.

Comment: Nice blog @ElmarBrauch. It fixed my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add devTools dependencies beyond starter-validation. Like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

if you want to remove the trace attribute, just add:

server.error.include-stacktrace=never

on application.properties